# How to toggle class when input length is not 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

How to add class when input [type="email"] has length > 0 and remove class if input length = 0?

Im not so good in javascript. The solution can be in vue.js or pure javascript.

I tried a few examples from the Internet, but without success.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" name="email" required>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
```

- add class if input length > 0
- remove class if input length = 0

Comment: Please post a minimal verifiable and complete example of your problem, we might be able to tell you what you are doing wrong. So far your post is just static HTML, where is the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by adding and removing class you mean the class of the div, then in jQuery it looks like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $("div").addClass("form-group");
    } else {
        $("div").removeClass("form-group");
    }
});
```

However if you want pure Javascript it would look something like this

```
<div id="myDiv" class="form-group">
  <input id="myInput" type="email" name="email" onChange="checkValue()" required>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
function checkValue(){
   if(document.getElementById("myInput").value.length > 0){
      document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("form-group");
   } else {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove("form-group");
   }
}
checkValue(); //First time run to see if input is empty or not
```

Comment: I modified it a bit for my requirements and works, thanks